# How can I insert the results of a stored procedure into a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[staffscorecard] 
    @STAFF_ID INT = NULL
as 
    select 
        count(STAFF_ID) as countexel 
    from 
        TbStudentSurvey 
    where 
        FEEDBACK = 'excellent' 
        and STAFF_ID = ISNULL(@STAFF_ID, STAFF_ID)

    select 
        Score as scoreexel 
    from 
        TbStaffScoreMaster 
    where 
        Status = 'Excellent' 

    exec [dbo].[staffscorecard]
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp ( countexel int, scoreexel int)
GO

INSERT INTO #temp (countexel , scoreexel)
   EXEC [dbo].[staffscorecard]
GO

SELECT *
FROM #temp
GO
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem clearly

Comment: I have created a stored procedure,Now I want to insert this procedure to a new table.How can i do that?

Comment: If you can user a table-valued function, you can do this in a function.  Instead of a temp table, use a table variable type.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx  This winds up looking something like `Select * from dbo.myFunctionName(@StaffId)`, which would return a table of values.  http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

Comment: Either you can use table-valued function or Put both columns in single select query then you can insert output to a temporary table.

Comment: Your SP returns only one field, instead your insert has two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given staffid to calculate countexel and scoreexel you can re-write your stored procedure as:

```
create table TbStudentSurvey (STAFF_ID int,FEEDBACK varchar(20));
insert into TbStudentSurvey values (1,'excellent'),(1,'excellent'),(2,'excellent');
create table TbStaffScoreMaster (Score int,[Status] varchar(20));
insert into TbStaffScoreMaster values(100,'Excellent');
Go

create procedure [dbo].[staffscorecard] 
    @STAFF_ID INT = NULL,
    @countexel int output,-- Explicitly declare output variables to fetch these values
    @scoreexel int output
as 
Begin 
    select 
        @countexel = count(STAFF_ID) 
    from 
        TbStudentSurvey 
    where 
        FEEDBACK = 'excellent' 
        and STAFF_ID = ISNULL(@STAFF_ID, STAFF_ID)

    select 
        @scoreexel = Score  
    from 
        TbStaffScoreMaster 
    where 
        Status = 'Excellent' 
End
GO
```

and then instead of using a temp table use a table variable because when you use temp tables,the table has to match the exact column layout as of the stored procedure.

```
--CREATE TABLE #temp (countexel int, scoreexel int)
--GO
--Create a table variable:
declare @temp table (countexel int, scoreexel int)
declare @countexel int, @scoreexel int,@STAFF_ID int;
--set value of staff Id for which you want to get countexel and scoreexel.
set @STAFF_ID = 1;
EXEC [dbo].[staffscorecard] @STAFF_ID ,@countexel output,@scoreexel output
INSERT @temp values (@countexel ,@scoreexel);

SELECT *
FROM @temp
GO
```

Method 2: 
You can also write as:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[staffscorecard] 
    @STAFF_ID INT = NULL    
as 
Begin 
    select 
        count(STAFF_ID) as countexel , Score as scoreexel
    from 
        TbStudentSurvey TSS
        inner join TbStaffScoreMaster TSM on TSM.Status = TSS.FEEDBACK 
    where 
        FEEDBACK = 'excellent' 
        and STAFF_ID = ISNULL(@STAFF_ID, STAFF_ID)   
     group by STAFF_ID,Score
End
GO

declare @temp table (countexel int, scoreexel int)
declare @STAFF_ID int;
set @STAFF_ID = 1;--set value of staff Id for which you want to get countexel and scoreexel.
INSERT @temp EXEC [dbo].[staffscorecard] @STAFF_ID 

SELECT *
FROM @temp
GO
```

Hope this helps!!